# Trying to Retrieve column name but gets column index from metadata via IBM JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, db2, websphere, database-metadata

I am using the jdbc driver for IBM DB2 Z/OS(version 4.13.127) and I am trying to get table information from the metadata.
I am having a different behaviour from what I was expecting : instead of retrieving the column names, I get the column indexes.

```
        ds=new com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource();
        ((com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource) ds).setServerName(ip);
        ((com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource) ds).setPortNumber(portNumber);
        ((com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource) ds).setDatabaseName(databaseName);
        ((com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource) ds).setDriverType(4);

        con = ds.getConnection(user, password);
        DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();

        rs = metadata.getTables(null, "MY_SCHEMA", "MY_TABLE", null);
        
        int columnsNumber = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
                String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            }
        }
```

The result is printed below :

```
null 1,  MY_SCHEMA 2,  MY_TABLE 3,  TABLE 4,   5,  null 6,  null 7,  null 8,  null 9,  null 10
```

I was expecting the `getColumnName` method to return the string attributes (table_name, schema_name, ...).
Is it specific to the db2 jdbc driver?

Comment: Have you tried using `getColumnLabel()` instead? The result set returned by `getTables()` is not backed by any real table, not directly anyway, so _column_ names may not exist, though labels probably do.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the missing fact - which __platform__ of Db2 (Z/OS, i-series,  linux/unix/windows) are you connecting to?  Also, you are using V10.5 fixpack0 (GA) jdbc driver, which is out of support. Please retry with a current jdbc driver version (v11.5.4 or higher).

Comment: This driver (4.13.127) is from very old Db2 version - 10.1 GA (even with no fixes). I can't reproduce such a result with my 4.25.1301, for example. [DB2 JDBC Driver Versions and Downloads](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads). What's your current Db2 version? Can you try a JDBC driver which corresponds to your version instead?

Comment: That was a driver version problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [this IBM technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/tech-tip-ibm-universal-jdbc-driver-behavior-when-calling-resultsetmetadatagetcolumnname-and-getcolumnlabel-against-db2-luw-server)  for information on using the Db2 specific driver property, `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics`.